When someone tells you, "you're a trip"
When I was having a conversation with someone and they looked at me and said "Man, You're a trip" was it referring to when I tripped over a word? Or didn't use the word right?

No, generally, it means you're unexpected in a good or bad way, depending on context (as mentioned). You're a breath of fresh air or way out in left field, and possibly talking to hippies or just bored.

I think this is a faux question, TBH. Look at the original…

That's just about as anachronistic as slang gets....post-hippie bs.

to me its where your tripping out on what someone is saying and they are taking it to seriously

I interpret "trip" as an intense and/or crazy experience. Depending on context it can be either positive or negative.

Right, and it originated with tripping i.e. taking psychedelic drugs like LSD.

I’m not sure if there are differences in this example between American and British (et.al.) English.
In regards to the “hippie“ comment, that population would use “tripping,” such as “You are tripping,” to mean odd or unusual behavior or speech.
“You’re a trip” generally has a positive connotation as different or fresh or funny or insightful in an ironic way.
Example Bob said, “The bicycle tire makes me hungry because it reminds me of a donut.
Friend: “You’re a trip.”
Compare to Bob said, “That bicycle tire makes me hungry.”
Friend:”Dude, you’re tripping.”

IMO it's kind of patronizing, right on the border between endearing and derisive. "Wow, that's original" with a hint of "bless your heart".

to trip was hippie talk for: taking psychedelic drugs. And it came to mean: Way out. Not just a regular, boring thing.

Green's Dictionary of Slang has many definitions of trip, both noun and verb.
The relevant one is noun 4.2d:

an odd, eccentric person; a funny person.

Green's labels this as US campus, i.e. college/university. Citations range from 1970 ("Dick Gregory was really a trip" - Gregory was a Black American comedian known for his radical political material) to 2022.
It derives ultimately from the drug slang meaning

1a the experience that follows the ingestion of LSD or another hallucinogenic, or occas. narcotic.

There is one citation from 1926 and more from the late 1960s onwards. From there, came various extended senses such as

2b a challenging, surprising or otherwise out of the ordinary experience; often as it’s a trip.

First citation of that is 1968, and from the sense of a surprising experience came a surprising person. So all these senses seem to have come into popularity in the late 60s and early 70s, which would tie in with the increased popularity of LSD and other psychedelics.
